# For loop homework

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

I have homework and these are my instructions:

1. create javascript 06.js with a general function: addThemUp()

   There is NO HTML page. There is NO EVENT HANDLER.
2. The function receives two parameters. They go between (..).
3. Use any names you want for the parameters but you could use descriptive names
4. Add all integers from the first parameter to the second.
5. All you need to do is use a for() loop and return the total.
6. Return the total of the integers. Use return because this is a general function.

Here is my code

```
function addThemUp(earlier,later) {
  var total = 0;
  for (i = 0; i <= earlier; i ++) {
      total = total + 0;
  };
  return total;
};
```

For some reason this one is messing up bad. We were able to do this exact same thing with Count but adding up and array seems to be different. When I run it through the grader I'm only receiving 25% grade.

Comment: This `for (i = 0; i <= earlier; i ++)` should be `for (var i = earlier; i <= later; i++)`. And this `total = total + 0;` should be `total = total + i;` or `total += i;`!

Comment: Please explain what you were trying to achieve with `total = total + 0;`

Comment: @Arkadiy I am fairly new to coding so im not sure. it was in an example in my textbook and thought it would work here. I understand what it means now. I was adding in increments of 0 so nothing was being added i is what i needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of both earlier and later in your loop:

```
function addThemUp(earlier,later) {

  var total = 0;

  for (i = earlier; i <= later; i ++) {

      total = total + i;

  };

  return total;
};
```

Comment: sigh........................................................... It has been a very long 24 hrs. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Downvoting, since this code is plainly wrong. The assignment states "_Add all integers from the first parameter to the second._", so `earlier` is an array and `later` is an atomic value. See Nelson Teixeira's answer for a valid solution.

Comment: ok so i did upvote @user7393973 but it doesnt show because im not 15 rep yet. not sure why you have to be a jerk about it. Also this code is correct. it scored 100% in the grader.

Comment: My answer was wrong. I misinterpreted the requests. This is the correct solution. Deleted the answer.  @user1438038 the correct interpretation is that he wants all integers ranging from one number to the other. So the first parameter isn't an array. It's just the lower limit.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be using

```
 i <= later
```

As it would stop on the first value otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

I'll point out two things that could help you on your way.

First: this line

```
total = total + 0;
```

Think about what it's doing for a bit.

`total` (which starts as `0`) is adding... `0`... to itself.  ;)

Next, this line:

```
for (i = 0; i <= earlier; i ++) {
```

IIRC, `earlier` is the *first* of the two numbers you're concerned about.

That part of the `for` loop says "stop when this condition is met." ;)

Comment: Yeah i ended up getting it a few minutes ago but thank you so much. I really appreciate the community on here.

Comment: Great :) Welcome!